# Photoresistors and RGB LEDS in c#

Tags: c#, arduino, rgb

I tried many times to write a code that, based on whether the lights (in the current room) are on or off, will make 2 RGB LED's blink or stay on in certain ways.
When the lights are on, the 2 RGBs are supposed to alternate blinking blue one second at a time.
When the lights are off, both RGBs are supposed to turn on, and stay, the color red.
I am using 2 RGBs, wires, a breadboard, resistors, a photoresistor, and an arduino UNO (not the original, but it is a pretty close replica... you can't tell any difference between the two besides the fact that it doesn't say "UNO"). The RGB's are connected to pins 5, 6, 7, and 8, 9, 10. The photoresistor is in pin 13.
This is the code I have currently(it's in c#, btw):

```
int sensPin = 13;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int prVal = analogRead(sensPin);
  Serial.write(prVal);
    if(prVal>225)
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(5,LOW);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(500);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the two RGBs are staying red... no matter what. I have tried fiddling with the wires, and triple-checking to see if everything is plugged in correctly, but no change happens. One other thing I find strange is that at random points, for a few split seconds, the RGBs (the lighting in the room hasn't changed and no hardware was touched or moved) will start alternately blinking blue, then go right back to staying red.

Any, and all suggestions and help is appreciated.

~edited~
I changed my code (and hardware) a bit. Due to a suggestion made in the comments, I put the photoresistor in pin 12, and changed my code accordingly. Also, a variable was changed (the name was sensPin, now it is declared as prPin), but not much else. Here's what I have:

```
int prPin = 12;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(prPin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int prVal = analogRead(prPin);
  Serial.write(prVal);
    if(prVal>225)
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(5,LOW);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
}
```

I uploaded the code, and ran it, but the same thing happened as last time.
Is it possible that I could have a bad board? I don't think that is the case, but there is a chance. I have tested everything on the board and everything seems okay... I don't know what's going on.
Once again, I would appreciate any help, whether a small tip or suggestion, or a definite thorough answer. I am an open book, so I'll accept anything you throw my way.

Comment: Sounds like you don't know if it's hardware or software... How about putting in some debugging output to find out?

Comment: What type of Arduino do you use? Uno? Mega? Leonardo? or other? In Arduino Uno, pin 13 is connected to the LED and it may be bad for reading analog values.

Comment: @Ian I already know that my problem isn't hardware because I have checked my circuit repeatedly and everything is right. I really need to know what I'm missing or doing wrong in my coding so I can fix this.

Comment: @MikeCat 
 
I am using a "counterfeit" arduino. It has "Itaduino" printed on it and works the same as an UNO. Are you sure that pin 13, being that there's an LED connected to it, isn't good for analog values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain pins, having specialized hardware, can be used as analog inputs.  These are marked A0-A5, and do not overlap with the digital pins IO0-IO13.

When you define

```
int prPin = 12;
```

then do not expect to call

```
analogRead(prPin)
```

with a meaningful result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm assuming that for the pin number (in the code) I type A0 or A(whatever pin), right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last code sample as mentioned by Ben Voight, you are confused with digital IO and ADC (analog to digital converter).

I would suggest to use RGB LED of type WS2812, they are well supported on Arduino require 1 digital IO supporting PWM (the one with the ~).

But you also ask about C#, there is this device called NusbioMCU, which allow any .NET language to control different shape of RGB LED WS2812 (Strip, Ring, Square). It also has 4 ADCs, one could be used to connect your photo resistor. And there is a lot of [samples on Github][1].

[image]